# Arithmetic calculation over rolling time window in R

Tags: r, loops

I have panel data and want to do a simple arithmetic calculation over specific rolling time frames (for example -12months to current) for every observation at every month in time:

.    "MRAR(1y)= ((sum(1+ER(-12,0))^-2)/12)-1". The ER data looks like this (expected output is on the very right. Please note that other observations include NAs).

```
ER.01.2014  ER.02.2014  ER.03.2014  ER.04.2014  ER.05.2014  ER.06.2014  ER.07.2014  ER.08.2014  ER.09.2014  ER.10.2014  ER.11.2014  ER.12.2014  MRAR(1Y).01.2015
-22.42      -12.67      18.61       22.31       -16.81      -45.44      138.84      50.71       -29.77      1.51        -15.35      -12.65      4.405833333
```

My approach would be the following:

```
ER <- as.data.frame(cbind(ER.08.2007, ER.09.2007, etc. 

cbind(time_series,seq(1:length(time_series)))

time_series <- c("08.2007","09.2007",etc.)

vars <- as.data.frame(cbind(names(ER),substr(names(ER),1,nchar(names(ER))-7),
                  substr(names(ER),nchar(names(ER))-6,nchar(names(ER))))) 

names(vars) <- c("ERdate","ER","date")

ERvars <- as.character(vars[vars$ER=="ER",][,"date"])

for (i in seq(1,length(time_series)))
    {
      aggregate(ER[i-36,0],df,sum)
}
```

..where the last line is just the inner part of the above formula.

I hope this goes in the right direction, the loop is where I run into problems.

```
Error in aggregate.data.frame(x, by, function(x) 0L) : 
  'by' must be a list
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, could you please use `dput(head(vars,10))` to show some sample input data and expected output. See here [how to post a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more suggestions.

Comment: Hello, thanks, I have provided this above now. The output from     dput is very lengthy even with     droplevels(), but I hope this suffices.

Comment: This does not yet help since we cannot see input data and expected output. Would suggest to include say maybe 12m data `(dateIndex, col1,col2,col3)` and expected output on 13th month for this subset period.

Comment: Thanks for help hNu, hope the above works for you?

Comment: See the `rollapply` function in the `zoo` package.

Comment: I think there are a couple of mistakes in your `for` loop, it seems to start at row 1 - 36 = –35 and iterates over the rows in the zeroth column 0 of ER. What is the object `df`?

Comment: Thanks Niek, I am making first steps on looping here, most likely more than one mistake indeed. Not even sure the aggregation syntax is appropriate for this? I want to iterate through columns actually, as the time-series runs through columns (see data example). Do you have a solution? Thanks, Wilhelm Fantastisch.